# I am working on Eclipse Juno, and when I click on Windows > File Explorer, it is not showing the data and other folders

Tags: android, database-connection, eclipse-juno

I was trying to establish database connectivity in Android. According to the tutorials I was referring to, it should show me some folders when I click on file explorer option in Windows tab. But no folder is shown there. Am I doing something wrong or is something wrong with the SQLite in my IDE?

Comment: What are you seeing when you click on `DDMS` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the emulator or device is connected and running. If not please connect and click on that device from device list and then click file explorer.

For reference:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Got it... One problem was that oracle was installed (somehow) on my lappy and it was not allowing to connect with db.